# If a user is required to provide an input to an array, if he leaves out an input, how does one set that element to 0?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2 dimensional array that is filled using input from the user.  I have most of the code done, but one of the requirements, even though its not what the assignment is actually about, is that if an element is left out of the user's input (they enter input separated by spaces), it is automatically set to 0.  How can I set that up?

Comment: What is the default value of elements in an *int* array?

Comment: How would an element be left out? Multiple spaces between elements? The left out elements at the end?

Comment: I can't quite get the question. Are you trying to replace the default value of the your int array from 0 to something else or you just asking why the default value is set to 0

Comment: post some relevant code

Comment: can u post the code where you fill the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At initialization, all elements in the array are set to a default value of null (Object/String), 0 (int/byte/float/double/short/long) or false (boolean). Provided no values are assigned at initialization, the elements should already hold this value so as long as the user input assigned does not change this it should already be set to 0 depending on primitive/object type.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that.  Does this apply to C++ also? just curious.

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
public static void main(String [] args) {

        int a[][] = new int[3][3];
        char ch;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 3*3 matrix :");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            String value = s.nextLine();
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                try {
                    ch = value.replace("\n", "").charAt(j);
                    if (ch == ' ') {
                        a[i][j] = 0;
                    } else {
                        a[i][j] = Character.getNumericValue(value.replace("\n",
                                "").charAt(j));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    // a[i][j]=0;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                System.out.print(" " + a[i][j]);
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
```

output :

```
 Enter 3*3 matrix :
  2
3   
 4 

 0 0 2
 3 0 0
 0 4 0
```